# Misunderstanding of J Tally(#)

Tags: arrays, rank, j

In J, to find the number of elements you can use # right?

e.g.

```
# 2 3 4 5 6
5
```

OK. So what about a multidimensional array

```
b=: 2 3 4 $ i.2

   b
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1

0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
```

Here #b is 2. I guess because the first dimension has length 2. i.e. the frame of the array.

So if I change it slightly:

```
b=:3 2 4 $ i.2
   b
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1

0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1

0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
```

This has tally 3, because the leading dimension has length 3, right?

But I can't explain this:

```
#\b
1 2 3
```

I run tally through the elements of b. So I would think each 2x4 sub array would be used and I would expect #\b to give

```
2 2 2
```

because:

```
c=:2 4 $i.2
   c
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
   #c
2
```

So my question is, why is #\b = 1 2 3? I think it has something to do with verb ranks, right? I'm struggling to understand this topic...

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that your misunderstanding is not to do with the verb `#` but with the adverb `\ ` . @Eelvex has done a great job of explaining the functionality of `\ ` below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to see what's going on is to box `<` your `\b`:

```
   <\b
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
│       │       │       │
│       │0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
│       │0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
│       │       │       │
│       │       │0 1 0 1│
│       │       │0 1 0 1│
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

`u\y` applies `u` to `y`'s prefixes:

```
<\1 2 3
┌─┬───┬─────┐
│1│1 2│1 2 3│
└─┴───┴─────┘
#\1 2 3
1 2 3
*/\1 2 3
1 2 6
```

So, `#\b` gives you the number of items of each of `b`'s prefixes.

What you probably thought you would get, is the 2-rank number of items of b:

```
#"2 b
2 2 2
<"2 b
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│0 1 0 1│
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of rank-0 items in a multidimensional array, do this:

```
   rank_0s =: */&$
   wild1 =: 2 3 4 $ 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

   rank_0s wild1
24
```